# Restructuring Panel Data in R - Years as Columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation, panel-data

In short: 
What I have:

```
ID  Name  wage2010  wage2011  wage2012  kids2010  kids2011  kids2012 
1  Chris   20,000    18,000    21,000     2          2        2
2  Pat     40,000    45,000    45,000     1          1        2
3  Susan   10,000    18,000    15,000     0          1        1
```

What I want:

```
ID  Name  year  wage  kids 
1   Chris 2010  20,000  2
1   Chris 2011  18,000  2
1   Chris 2012  21,000  2
2   Pat   2010  40,000  1
2   Pat   2011  45,000  1
2   Pat   2012  45,000  2
3   Susan 2010  10,000  0
3   Susan 2011  18,000  1
3   Susan 2012  15,000  1
```

Any help suggestions? Thanks in avdance.

Comment: Hi, you should look at the functions [`pivot_*`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html) in package `tidyr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns('^wage', '^kids'),
    variable.name = 'year', value.name = c('wage', 'kids'))
```

---

Or with `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(df1, cols = -c(ID, Name), 
   names_to = c( '.value', 'year'), names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])")
# A tibble: 9 x 5
#     ID Name  year  wage    kids
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <int>
#1     1 Chris 2010  20,000     2
#2     1 Chris 2011  18,000     2
#3     1 Chris 2012  21,000     2
#4     2 Pat   2010  40,000     1
#5     2 Pat   2011  45,000     1
#6     2 Pat   2012  45,000     2
#7     3 Susan 2010  10,000     0
#8     3 Susan 2011  18,000     1
#9     3 Susan 2012  15,000     1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Name = c("Chris", "Pat", "Susan"),
wage2010 = c("20,000", 
"40,000", "10,000"), wage2011 = c("18,000", "45,000", "18,000"
), wage2012 = c("21,000", "45,000", "15,000"), kids2010 = 2:0, 
    kids2011 = c(2L, 1L, 1L), kids2012 = c(2L, 2L, 1L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```